# facilitate iteration between DOCX tracked changes and QMD

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, quarto

For Rmarkdown there are a few solutions that allow you to ingest tracked changes from a rendered DOCX into your `*.RMD`. One notable one is `{redoc}`, called out in Xie, Dervieux, & Riederer's (2022) very good [**R Markdown Cookbook**](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-redoc.html).

I have a report build as a `{quarto}` book that I am in the process of review/editorial with the customer. It would be nice to ingest the customer's DOCX tracked changes into my QMD file(s). Is there a package that does that?

To my knowledge, `{redoc}` is RMD-specific. Thanks in advance!